# How do I migrate from Google Cloud SQL to AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Im trying to migrate from Google Cloud SQL to AWS RDS but there is a issue with the IAM Role.

I have managed to export the data from Google Cloud SQL and upload it to a S3 Bucket. I tried creating a role with all permissions and one with the permission that it says the account is missing.

When I try to create the database from the S3 Backup it says

```
IAM role ARN value is invalid or does not include the required permissions for: S3_SNAPSHOT_INGESTION (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 5a17c666-0e39-48bb-b667-1ab8c13c19b1)
```

Comment: We are not using SAML 2.0 or PIM and PAM.

Answer (score 0):

You [need to provide permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html#MySQL.Procedural.Importing.Enabling.IAM) to pass the role to the RDS service, for example:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
    [
        {
            "Sid":"AllowS3AccessRole",
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":"iam:PassRole",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:iam::IAM User ID:role/S3Access"
        }
    ]
}
```